# Handling window changed signals in QQuickItem subclass

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm looking at some demo source code that subclasses QQuickItem. The constructor has this:

```
 connect(this, SIGNAL(windowChanged(QQuickWindow*)), this, SLOT(handleWindowChanged(QQuickWindow*)));
```

I cannot figure out where this `windowChanged` signal is coming from. It shows as emitting from `this` but neither this subclass or the `QQuickItem` class list this function anywhere. What does it mean?

`handleWindowChanged` is implemented in this subclass, but I do not know where the signal `windowChanged` comes from. Is this a signal generated somewhere else in the Qt environment? Doesn't the `this` indicate that it should be emitting from this subclass or its baseclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the demo source you're looking at is [from here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/scenegraph-openglunderqml.html).

As it's a Qt 5.1 demo, checking the [Qt 5.1 docs for QQuickItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/qquickitem.html#signals), there is a signal defined in that class: -

```
void windowChanged(QQuickWindow * window)
```

Comment: Ah, no wonder! I was looking at the 5.0 class documentation for QQuickItem and saw nothing. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, it's easily missed ;O)